# Remove header sign in link from magento 2 one page checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have been playing around with removing elements on magento 2's one page checkout. Not sure how to remove the sole sign in link provided during checkout in the header. The code below does not work in `cart_index_index.xml`. Any help is appreciated.

```
  <referenceBlock name="authentication-wrapper" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: are u talk about which page checkout or cart?

Comment: The checkout page, where the shipping is entered. By default magento removes all links and provides a sign in link if the user is not currently signed in. I'm looking for a way to remove the sign in link as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the layout file `magento_checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` to your module or theme with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This disables the JS component that renders the authentication element.

Comment: For people who don't understand how to do this, you have to place above file under `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: Thanks worked great from my end!!!